# PHP str_replace doesn't work on JSON string

Tags: php, json, str-replace

Im outputting some data as JSON and Im trying to replace the brackets '[' in the output with HTML tags:

```
$qq = json_decode($html, true);
$qq2 = str_replace("[","<span>",$qq);

print_r($qq2);
```

It doesn't work, meaning the brackets show up anyway and are not getting replaced.
Example output:

```
 [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [image] => http://rack.0.mshcdn.com/james-clapper.jpg
                                    [query] => (max-width: 480px)
                                    [size] => 80x80#
                                )
```

I would like to replace the brackets as html tags so the output will 
be:

```
 [2] => Array
                                (
                                    <span> image </span> => http://rack.0.mshcdn.com/james-clapper.jpg
                                    <span> query </span> => (max-width: 480px)
                                    <span> size </span> => 80x80#
                                )
```

Comment: It appears as though you're trying to replace the text on an array not a string. http://us3.php.net/json_decode

Comment: Are you saying what I'm trying to do is impossible? Basically Im trying to "prettify" the json by transforming it in HTML tags. Is that not possible like this..?

Comment: As RyanS notes, $qq is an array, not a JSON string.  Either way, you shouldn't be using str_replace for this.  Simply iterate the array and create a string that has your formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use http://www.php.net/array_walk after you decode the string to apply str_replace to every member of the array.

Comment: Nice, if you only need to add HTML tags to the array keys, instead of using str_replace you can append and preppend them in the callback function as <span>.$key.</span>